# Dockerfile to containerize a react,nodejs,mongodb application

Tags: node.js, docker

I am new to React, Node.j and MongoDB stack. I want to containerize the application and make a docker image for deployment in kubernetes. The github repository url is:

https://github.com/drminnaar/noteworx-react-mongodb.git

Am confused in how to write the dockerfile and the steps to containerize after the dockerfile is done.
Can anyone help me to write the dockerfile for the above application code and steps to make docker image for it.

```
FROM node:8         
WORKDIR   /app           
COPY package*.json  ./           
RUN npm install           
COPY   .   .         
RUN npm run build                                                                  
RUN npm run lint          
EXPOSE 3000                     
CMD ["npm", "run",  "serve:api"]
```

Actually iam working with my azure vm.The dockerfile I have written is the above one, but its not working after making docker images using this dockerfile and running the docker image.The backend port number in the code is `8000`,I dockerfile i have exposed `3000` for frontend and accessing the application using `publicipf azurevm:3000`,but its not accessible.

Please give me the dockerfile to create docker image of the application code in the mentioned github repo.

**Note**: I have exposed the port number 3000 on security group.

Comment: How exactly isn't it working?  How did you start the container?  You mention "public IP" and "security group"; are you trying to run this on a public-cloud system, and if so, does the container work on your local system?

Comment: No,i am using an azure vm and i cloned the above mentioned github repo to my azure vm.in the github repo there is "Client" directory for frontend and "Server" directory for backend and on the parent directory in which both "Client" and "Server" also contains package.json and package-lock.json.So to containerize i wrote the above dockerfile,but i am doubt in that its right or not,because i am new this reactjs,nodejs,mongodb stack.Its not working with my dockerfile,i think its wrong one.Actually i am seeking help in how to wrote the dockerfile for containerizing the mentioned application code.

Comment: You wouldn't put each of those things in one Dockerfile. Use Docker compose. Use 3 containers. And don't use legacy Nodejs versions

Comment: But there is only one package.json file

Comment: What is the docker run command you are using?

Comment: Docker command using is:-    docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name myapp <imageid>